# Issue with substring removal Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string

I am trying to remove a sub string from a string in the data downloaded using REST query, I am using "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" to replace @"Point" with @"" and storing it in a temp variable, but the original variable and the temp variable are not updating.

```
-(void)fetchURL:(NSURL *)url
{

url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://team41.kmiller.io/api/getByLocation/Verizon%20Wireless/100/33.7/-84.0"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];

         if ([[greeting objectForKey:@"result"] isEqualToString:@"success"])
         {
             NSString * temp;
             for(NSDictionary* key in [greeting objectForKey:@"json"])
             {
                 NSString * strength = [key objectForKey:@"dbm_strength"];
                 NSString * location = [key objectForKey:@"astext(location)"];
                 temp = [location stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Point" withString:@""];
                 NSLog(@"%@",location);
                 NSLog(@"%@",temp);
                 break;
             }


             // TODO: Parse location and strength
             // TODO: Update the records to database
         }
     }
 }];
}
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `location` variable?

Comment: So what is the `NSLog` outputting?

Comment: was P in the Point capitalized in the location?

Comment: Sorry about the NSLOG thing, I was checking the values through a debugger so didn't notice that there was a semantic issue, fixed the NSLog thing, but its still showing no change in variables

Comment: Yes, 'P' was capitalized.

Comment: Show the log output you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST response is `POINT` and you are trying to replace `Point`

The actual response

```
"POINT(33.78272 -84.40426)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't believe I was making such a silly mistake.

Comment: It happens to all of us.

Answer (score 0):

While Vig's answer is correct and points out **one** problem, there is a worse one: subStringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: returns a new NSString*. It doesn't modify the receiver of the message. The modified string is stored in temp, passed to NSLog, then thrown away. This code will not store the result anywhere.